# Do dictionaries of equivalent objects not work, or have I done something wrong?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have a class

```
Public Class Person
Public Name As String
Public Rank As String
End Class
```

And then I have a dictionary which uses these classes as the Key. I have two Person objects, each with the same string value in Name and Rank, but I find that they are not treated as the same key. Can the dictionary not be used this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dictionary does not know how to compare your user-made classes by default. It does *not* simply compare all fields within the class. As noted in the [remarks section for Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

Your person class must implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface, consisting of an `Equals(Person)` method, which will return true if the two instances should be treated as equal. Additionally, as noted in [remarks for IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base class implementations of `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method.